# finding the first index that unbalances brackets in a string

Tags: python-3.x

given a string that includes unbalanced brackets of some order, how can I find the first index that is the unbalancing factor of my string and return it?

for example: if the string is: ")" the return value will be 0 ,
             if the string is: "(((jjkk))))" the return value will be 10 ,
             if the string is: "((" the return value will be 2 ,

I have implemented a function that returns boolean regarding if my string is balanced or not. (T - balanced)
I know it should be some recursive function but just can't figure it out...
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need a recursive function. To me it looks like a regular looping over the characters of the string and counting left and right brackets.

Comment: Keep track of the current depth, return the index if the depth is lower than zero.

Comment: I find it hard to understand your explanations, it has to be recursive. can you implement this algorithm in python3 or in pseudocode?

Comment: Who told you about that it *has to be* recursive? (No, I don't really want to know.) Look at my answer.

Comment: You forgot to either accept an answer or to comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

A nonrecursive solution (written in pseudosomething loosely resembling C#) ...

```
string input_str = "this(is(for)(testing))(the)correctness)(of(brackets))";
int left_brackets_cnt = 0;

for (int i=1; i<=input_str.length; i++)
{
    switch (input_str.char_at_position(i))
    {
        case "(": left_brackets_cnt++;
        case ")": left_brackets_cnt--;
    }

    if (left_brackets_cnt < 0)
        throw exception("Unmatched right bracket at position "+i);
}

if (left_brackets_cnt > 0)
    throw exception("Too many left brackets");
```

*Footnote:* Please show appreciation - I typed this on a 3" smartphone! :-)